# Customer/Company Address/Phone Numbers

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-normalization

I have a database design requirement that is getting increasingly complex for me to figure the best way of approaching.

Currently, I have "contacts", and I have "companies". A company can have multiple contacts, but a contact can only belong to one company. This makes an obvious 1:n relationship. However, a contact does not *have* to have a company; mainly a residential/non-business customer (thus would be referred to as a "customer" on the front-end). This turns it into a 0:n relationship it seems.

The `contacts` table has a simple foreign key to the `id` of the `companies` table to establish this relationship.

The problem comes with storing addresses and phone numbers. Currently, the `contacts` table and `companies` table **both** store a single address and two phone numbers each (static columns). In most cases, the software simply mirrors the same data in both tables; the "company" data is shown as prevalent when it is available (aka the customer does not have the `id` of "0" for its company). This causes some confusion to the end user, and also has severe limitations.

I am in need of revamping this design in order to store multiple addresses (billing, ship to, etc), and of course as many phone numbers as I want. This is especially for companies that may have multiple facilities and one central billing office of course.

At first, I think of making the 1:n for the addresses against the `companies` table; however, the `contacts` also needs its potential separate data. This mostly gets complicated since a contact, as mentioned before, does not *have* to have a company, and could be a stand-alone. The company needs a master list of addresses for probably billing purposes, then the contact may need their own list of addresses for service and such. Or, the company could simply have all the addresses (could be best for statistics), and then the contact has only their primary address or something.

How can I go about putting this all together? Do I have one table for all contact/company addresses, or do I need seperate tables (`contacts_addresses` and `companies_addresses`)? I will of course use the same strategy for phone numbers.

The more I research, the more I get confused to be honest with so many answers and approaches. The leading one so far for my application sounds like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550046/customer-address-property-address-and-company-address). According to this, should I have the 1:n relationship with the `companies` table, and then a simple 1:1 relationship for the `contacts`? If this is the case, do I have `contacts` refer to the same table (and have a dropdown of the addresses linked with their company for a choice, and an option to make a new one), or have simple static columns in the `contacts` table?

Comment: FWIW, we insist that all contacts belong to at least one organization - although that 'organization' can be, for instance, a family/residential unit, e.g. '32 Elm Street' or even 'Some project'

Comment: Would [this design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641661/database-design-multiple-contact-information-for-different-tables/19643551#19643551) work for you?

Comment: @BennyHill That design looks promising at first to me, but I do not want the many-to-many relationships it appears to have for everything, especially for companies and contacts. I do not want a contact to be able to link to multiple companies for our system's purposes. I also do not want multiple addresses to belong to multiple companies; I'd rather have duplicates so that an address change in one company does not affect the other company.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm starting to see that as a possible solution, but I really don't want to go that specific route. A prior system we used to use (and I had to nightmarishly import from) used that approach (and I now understand why). It was a major pain to the end user though, with having to select "Residential" for the organization each time, which made for alot of confusion when it was missed. Although, that gives me the idea of simply making the id 0 an entry in the `companies` table so that the subsequent JOINS would work, instead of 0 being an "ignore me" value.

Comment: @Strawberry Actually, nevermind on my thoughts of the 0 being a valid entry to JOIN to. The reason I don't want all contacts to belong to a central organization is that they would all share the same address entries, etc.(!) This is what makes me want to connect the addresses to the `contacts` table.

Comment: That's why I say that the address itself can be the organisation. It doesn't have to be PRIMARY (i.e. it can change). It just has to be UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1):

An individual and an organization are concrete representations of an abstract Legal Party (This is called the Party Model).

```
Individual : Party
Organization : Party
```

An email address, web address, phone number, physical address can be thought of concrete representations of an abstract address.

```
EmailAddress : Address
WebAddress : Address
PhoneNumber : Address
PhysicalAddress : Address
```

An address can be unoccupied. A person can have multiple addresses. Multiple people can share one address.

Therefore there is a many-to-many relationship between Party and Address:

```
Party -< ContactMethod >- Address
```

Where `ContactMethod` has a `role` label, such as "Work", "Home", etc. The more specialized `PhoneContactMethod` might have an `Extension` column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on that. My question with a many-to-many relationship, is what happens when someone changes their address? This system will be prone to user errors for sure (by nature), so I don't want Jeff's address change (or typo-fix even) to affect Jim's when they are both pointing to the same record. Am I incorrect in assuming the only way to avoid this is to make it one-to-many? Or even make it just make a new record on any edits? That seems to open too many problems to me.

Comment: I would start w strong validation up-front, ie checking the address against a web service like USPS to make sure it's valid. Could also create new address and assign it to Jim.

Comment: I do use Google Maps to verify the address in a visual way to the user, but this is part of a company's POS-style system, so it is prone to miscommunication between the user and the customer, especially with accents and over the phone, lol. So with this many-to-many relationship, you are saying that I should be making a new address for every user still? How does it still require a m:n relationship then?

Comment: If you have a very wrong address, assigned to one person, then you could just update the address. It would be odd to have a very wrong address assigned to more than one person. If you did though, you could either create a new address and assign it to the guy that corrected it and leave it for the other people (and maybe notify admin to double check)